# ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected in Oracle ADF

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

Why would I get the above SQL error from Oracle via a Java application for this query?

```
SELECT * FROM TestSchema.TestTable
WHERE userid = :userId
AND transactionDate BETWEEN TO_DATE(:start_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
AND TO_DATE(:end_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Comment: I think, you should put the parameters values `:userId, :start_date, :end_date` in your question, for receiving more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  In this example, there is no need for the `to_date` functions on `start_date` and `end_date.`  This worked just fine:

```
SELECT * FROM TestSchema.TestTable
WHERE userid = :userId
AND transactionDate BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date
```